# Was Jesus given power (Acts 10:38)

Tags: christology, acts

> And you know that God anointed Jesus of Nazareth ***with the Holy Spirit
> and with power***. Then Jesus went around doing good ***and healing*** all who
> were oppressed by the devil, for God was with him. (Acts 10:38)

Does this verse say that Jesus was given power by God to work miracles? If so, how can we say that Christ's miracles are proof of his deity if Christ wasn't doing miracles by virtue of a power *inherent* to him by virtue of his divine nature, but rather by the power *given* to him by God?

Further reading (specifically commentaries) on this issue would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The Bible's own testimony is usually better than any commentary.  Here are scriptures that address your question.

> <sup>6</sup>But that ye may know that **the Son of man hath power** on
> earth to forgive sins, (then saith he to the sick of the palsy,)
> Arise, take up thy bed, and go unto thine house. <sup>7</sup>And he
> arose, and departed to his house. <sup>8</sup>But when the multitudes
> saw it, they marvelled, and **glorified God, which had given such
> power unto men**. (Matthew 9:6-8, KJV)

Evidently, it was clear to the observers where the power had come from.

> And when he had called unto him his twelve disciples, he gave them
> **power** against unclean spirits, to cast them out, and to heal all
> manner of sickness and all manner of disease. (Matthew 10:1, KJV; cf. Mark 6:7; Luke 9:1)

The disciples also received power that would not normally be theirs.  Demons are not cast out by mere human power, yet the disciples were not to be thought of as Gods by virtue of having used God's power to do this.

> And Jesus came and spake unto them, saying, **All power is given unto me**
> in heaven and in earth. (Matthew 28:18, KJV)

Jesus himself acknowledges that his power had been given to him.

> And Jesus returned **in the power of the Spirit** into Galilee: and there
> went out a fame of him through all the region round about. (Luke 4:14,
> KJV)

The text says Jesus returned "in the power of the Spirit."  It does not say he returned in his own power.  That Jesus was not Spirit himself is clear in Luke 24:39:

> Behold my hands and my feet, that it is I myself: handle me, and see;
> for a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see me have. (Luke 24:39,
> KJV)
>
> <sup>42</sup>And as he was yet a coming, the devil threw him down, and
> tare him. And Jesus rebuked the unclean spirit, and healed the child,
> and delivered him again to his father. <sup>43</sup>And they were all
> amazed at **the mighty power of God.** But while they wondered every one
> at all things which Jesus did, . . . (Luke 9:42-43, KJV)

The people knew that humans do not have power to cast out the demons.

> <sup>1</sup>These words spake Jesus, and lifted up his eyes to heaven,
> and said, Father, the hour is come; glorify thy Son, that thy Son also
> may glorify thee: <sup>2</sup>As **thou hast given him power** over all
> flesh, that he should give eternal life to as many as thou hast given
> him. <sup>3</sup>And this is life eternal, that they might know thee
> the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent. (John
> 17:1-3, KJV)

Jesus acknowledges that his Father, whom he calls "the only true God," is the one who gave the Son his power.

**Conclusion**

The Bible is clear that God had given Jesus his power.  Jesus himself attests to this.

Comment: 1. Most of the verses you sent aren't relevant whatsoever. Those verses aren't speaking about the power to perform miracles but rather the power to forgive sins, which is best translated as authority. It's interesting how you leave out v. 3 where the Pharisees accuse Jesus of blasphemy since they believed Christ was carrying out a divine prerogative (they explicitly say this in Mark's account). Matthew 28:18 and John 17:2 are likewise referring to authority, not the power to perform miracles, which is what I was asking about.

Comment: 2. If Jesus returning in the power of the Spirit means he returned in a power that isn't his, then by that logic God working through the power of the Spirit means he was working through a power that wasn't his either (Zechariah 4:6, Job 33:4, Psalm 104:30, Exodus 31:3, Exodus 35:31)

Comment: 3. Unless you presuppose that Christ isn't God himself, Luke 9:43 doesn't prove anything. In fact, a Trinitarian could just as easily say that Christ had the power of God because he himself *is* God.

Comment: I asked about Acts 10:38 specifically and you went off topic about how Christ was given power according to other verses, something I didn't ask about. Not only that, but you blatantly distorted said verses to fit a Unitarian narrative. Very disappointing.

Comment: @bob  If you are so intent on finding your own doctrines supported in the Bible, rather than finding your doctrines from what the Bible teaches, perhaps you should consider making your own Bible version to say what you want it to say.  On the other hand, if you read from enough commentaries, surely you will find one of the commentarians who agrees with your views--keep looking!

Comment: Luke 4:14 is definitely one of the most relevant verses here, yeah.  It shows that the power comes from the in-dwelling of the Holy Spirit, and in turn, when cross-referenced with Acts 1:4-8, explains how those who are baptised with the Holy Spirit receive that same power and are able to perform the miracles that Jesus said we would do (in John 14:12).

Comment: The thing to remember, @bob, is that Bible verses don't exist in a void.  You can't take one verse, make a doctrine out of your own interpretation of it, and then throw away the rest of the Bible; rather, you cross-reference it with other verses to make sure that you understand correctly.  In this case, you should indeed look at other verses about Jesus receiving power, to learn _how_ and _why_ He received power.  You can't divorce Acts 10:38 from the rest of the Bible, and demand that people only look at that one verse and nothing else to explain that one verse.  [To be continued.]

Comment: [Continuation, @bob.]  And even if you wish to throw away as much of the Bible as possible, then you have to look at the context of the verse to understand the verse.  In this case, Peter is witnessing to Gentiles about Jesus, and then goes on to say that the apostles are witnesses of everything Jesus did (which includes the works mentioned in Acts 10:38).  Since the topic of the discussion is proof of Jesus' divinity, you may want to look at the witnesses... so go to John 8:18, where Jesus says that the Father, God, bears witness that His claims are true.  Who did the power come from, again?

Comment: Your answer ignores the context. Peter is speaking to Cornelius, his relatives, and his close friends. It is unreasonable to extract this one statement from Peter speech and show its meaning not by anything else Peter says to the group, but what is written elsewhere. Especially since most if not all of your supporting arguments were not written and surely not known to Cornelius or anyone else listening to Peter.

Comment: @RevelationLad Peter is the one teaching Cornelius, not the other way around. Therefore, one would not _expect_ that Cornelius would have, or even need, the additional context you seem to require.  The one who needs that context in this conversation is Peter himself--and he certainly had it. Jesus had taught the disciples quite plainly that everything he did was through the Father's power. Consider: _"Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and the Father in me? the words that I speak unto you I speak not of myself: but **the Father that dwelleth in me, he doeth the works**" (John 14:10)._

Comment: 1) You are dismissing the practical consequence of what Peter is saying. For example how is Cornelius going to understand Peter's claim Jesus is *Lord of all*? Isn't a Roman Centurion who is required to worship Caesar as God going to understand that as expressing the deity of Jesus? 2) Peter does not say Jesus worked miracles. He says He did so while **anointed with the Holy Spirit**. From Peter's perspective you cannot lump all miracles into one group, as you do. You need to distinguish those described with the Holy Spirit from those lacking that attribute.

Comment: @RevelationLad Perhaps you are dismissing Cornelius' own experience.  Do you recall the reason for Cornelius' search for Peter to come and to teach him?  It certainly had nothing to do with Caesar prompting him.  (See Acts 10:1-8.)

Comment: While I am not going to ignore history nor overlook the fact it was not just Cornelius who received the Holy Spirit. It was his relatives and close friends. You want to justify a certain position using things those listening were unlikely to know. At the same time, you want to ignore the things they actually heard Peter say.  A far-fetched and unlikely position IMO.

Comment: @RevelationLad God was involved in the whole process, as you know and I believe would agree.  But God has never been seen, nor heard, by men.  See John 5:37.  Neither Peter nor Cornelius could possibly have seen or heard God Himself.  God's Spirit is His representative to us, and Jesus is our Mediator, the Word--the spokesperson/messenger for God.  I really don't understand what you are disagreeing with, nor what you are claiming that I am ignoring.  You aren't making much sense to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147416/discussion-between-revelation-lad-and-biblasia).

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who claims that Jesus' miracles were evidence of His divinity is making a serious theological mistake - there were plenty of others who worked miracles who did not claim to be divine such as, The Apostle Paul, the Apostle Peter, many of the OT prophets, etc.

Thus, miracles are no evidence, and cannot be used as evidence of divinity of the miracle worker.  At best, miracles are evidence of a divine power, but none of the people above claimed to be divine, just that they had God working through them.  Matt 10:8, Mark 16:17, 20, Acts 2:22, 43, 4:30, 5:12, 6:8, 8:6, 13, 14:3, 15:12, 19:11, Rom 15:18, 19, 2 Cor 12:12, Heb 2:4 speak of the signs and wonders accompanying the apostles’ ministry.

Indeed, it was Jesus Himself who said this about the miracles He performed:

> John 14:12 - Very truly I tell you, whoever believes in me will do the
> works I have been doing, and **they will do even greater things than
> these**, because I am going to the Father.

If one seeks evidence of Christ's divinity (or otherwise) one must seek it elsewhere.  Jesus had the gift of the Holy Spirit, but so does every Christian.  1 Cor 12, 14, etc.

Jesus' anointing by the Holy Spirit is recorded by all the Gospel accounts at His baptism, Acts 4:27, 10:38, Luke 4:18, Heb 1:9; and this anointing occurred at Jesus' water baptism when the Holy Spirit descended like a dove, Matt 3:16, 17, Mark 1:10, 11, Luke 3:21, 22, John 1:32.

As to whether Jesus' power to perform these miracles is bestowed or innate is a highly controversial subject and good cases have been made for both sides.  However, because Jesus' life was supposed, despite His divinity, to be an example to us, I firmly believe that despite having the innate power to do much (eg, John 10:18), Jesus used only delegated power to do miracles as shown by John 14:12 quoted above.

Comment: +1 Well said--and I nearly added something similar to my response.

Comment: Did any other make the blind to see ? Did any other still the waves of the sea ? Did any other rise from the dead without another influence ? Did ever men fall backwards at the word 'I am' other than at his word ? (I'm just asking . . . . . . )

Comment: The response addresses evidence of Jesus's divinity. It doesn't address whether Jesus's power was received or not.

Comment: @NigelJ - Peter raised someone from the dead; Paul healed people; etc.  See • Matt 10:8, Mark 16:17, 20, Acts 2:22, 43, 4:30, 5:12, 6:8, 8:6, 13, 14:3, 15:12, 19:11, Rom 15:18, 19, 2 Cor 12:12, Heb 2:4

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic Christian belief that Jesus is fully human and fully divine. What is meant by 'fully human'? and did Jesus carries His divine power when He walked on earth? There are a few verses that might help to shed the light regrading to the question.

> 6 Who, being in very nature God, **did not consider equality with God something to be used to his own advantage**;
>
> 7 rather, **he made himself nothing** by taking the very nature of a servant,
> **being made in human likeness**.
>
> 8 And being found in appearance as a man, **he humbled himself**
> by becoming obedient to death—even death on a cross! (Philippians 2:6-8 NIV)

Paul wrote Jesus did not used His divine nature as His own advantage when Jesus walked on earth, and He made himself likeness of a human. A human cannot perform miracle without divine assist. In this sense, I agree that Jesus was given power by God thru the Holy Spirit to work miracles. For Jesus as a human, baptised with the Holy Spirit and the Holy Spirit is with Him at all time, until the moment He was on the cross, that the Holy Spirit left Him when He cried *“My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?”* (Matthew 27:46), then He died.

In John, there is a dialogue from Jesus

> 17 The reason my Father loves me is that I lay down my **life**—only to take it up again.
>
> 18 No one takes **it** from me, but I lay **it** down of my own accord. I have authority to lay **it** down and authority to take **it** up again. This command I received from my Father.” (John 10:17-18 NIV)

The word 'life' in 10:17, or 'it' in 10:18 is generally referring to His crucifixion and subsequent resurrection. Literally it is but there seems to have something not quite right. If 'life' means human life, at His resurrection  'it' is no longer human, for human will die again. Why would Jesus take 'a human life' up again? Certainly 'it' in John 10:18 means his divine nature. Then we can rewrite John 10:18 as this

> No one takes *my divine nature* from me, but I lay *my divine nature* down of my own accord. I have authority to lay *my divine nature* down and authority to take *my divine nature* up again. This command I received from my Father.”

So when Jesus lay down His divine nature, He became fully human. Jesus performed miracles thru the assist of the Holy Spirit, for God is with Him. At His resurrection, He resumed His fully divine nature.

Comment: How do you reconcile these two statements of yours? -->  _"It is a basic Christian belief that Jesus is fully human and fully divine. "_ AND _"So when Jesus lay down His divine nature, He became fully human."_

Comment: @Biblasia. Someone in my neighbourhood also happens to be the mayor of this city.  Even though she is always fully my mayor, whenever we meet on the street or at community gatherings, she temporarily lays aside that position and is simply a normal member of the neighbourhood.

Comment: It is not possible to 'lay down divine nature' nor did the Son of God 'become fully human'. Nor did he discard humanity and 'resume divine nature'. Taking humanity once, he dwells in humanity eternally - 'God manifest in flesh'. 'Basic Christian belief' (as you say) does not agree with you. See the Council of Nicaea.

Comment: Thank you for all comments. Sin is a debt to God, a sinner cannot repay the debt of another sinner. Jesus has no sin, therefore his sacrifice on the cross repay the sin of mankind, for those who believe in Him. If Jesus died on the cross as God, then He didn't have to made human. Jesus was a human when He walked on earth, no difference to any human in terms of our emotion, needs and capability. He demonstrated to His disciples through faith, miracle will be given. Jesus healed the sick did not say because I am God, He said because of your faith.

Comment: Jesus told His disciples if their faith was strong enough, they could walk on water and move mountains. Jesus must not be lying. So if His disciples could perform miracles and they were not God, it was Holy Spirit did for them. I am not saying Jesus is fully human and fully God at the same time. He was fully human only at time of His incarnation. Other time He is fully God. If the phrase 'divine nature' is not proper, please suggest a better one. I do have problem to make myself clear sometimes.

Comment: @VincentWong Most of what you have said in the two comments above is correct.  "Divine" can mean "like God" or "from God," and certainly that fits Jesus, even if Jesus is not God--check the dictionary.  I think, actually, Jesus has "divine nature," but many English speakers mistake that to mean that he is God.  They don't understand what the term actually means.  The Bible teaches that "God was in Christ" (2 Corinthians 5:19), not that God _was_ Christ, nor that Christ _was_ God.  He himself says he is sent _from_ God (John 8:42).

Comment: @Biblasia - it is about the perception of the identity of Jesus before His incarnation and after His crucifixion. I find it is not something for debate instead sharing the view is more valuable.

Comment: @VincentWong Jesus words recorded in Luke 24:39 were post-resurrection.  He was still flesh, as we are.

Comment: @Biblasia - You raise a good point, that some may puzzle was Jesus still a human or He is God the 40 days before His ascension. God can appear as human, as He met Abraham and wrestling with Jacob. I don't mean I am sure and telling people this is the fact. I am giving my belief to share, if my view is beneficial to others.

Answer (score 0):

**Miracle Worker**
While the Bible describes God working miracle throughout history, it must be noted Jesus performed miracles which were never done by others:

> Never since the world began has it been heard that anyone opened the eyes of a man born blind. (John 9:32 ESV)

Two miracles during the Exodus involved crossing bodies of water: at the Red Sea and then at the Jordan River. In both, the water was parted. Jesus did something greater:

> And in the fourth watch of the night he came to them, walking on the sea. (Matthew 14:25; also Mark 6:48 and John 6:19)

The Israelites walked on dry land. Jesus walked on water without getting wet. He also showed the power to get others across water without the need of dry land:

> <sup>28</sup> And Peter answered him, “Lord, if it is you, command me to come to you on the water.” <sup>29</sup> He said, “Come.” So Peter got out of the boat and walked on the water and came to Jesus. (Matthew 14)

Jesus was not just "another" miracle worker. Jesus worked unique miracles, setting Him apart from all others, before and after.

**Isaiah 63**
It is important to consider all Peter said about the miracles:

> how God anointed Jesus of Nazareth with the Holy Spirit and with power. He went about doing good and healing all who were oppressed by the devil, for God was with him.
> (Acts 10:38)

Peter states the miracles Jesus did were done while being anointed **with the Holy Spirit**. So if miracles are going to be used as a "test" of deity, the correct use of miracles is to compare those done with the Holy Spirit. The OT has only one miracle which includes the Holy Spirit:

> <sup>11</sup> Then they remembered the ancient days, <sup>c-</sup>Him, who pulled his people<sup>-c</sup> out [of the water]: "Where is He who brought them up from the Sea along with the shepherd<sup>d</sup> of His flock? Where is He who put in their midst His holy spirit, <sup>12</sup> who made His glorious arm
> march at the right hand of Moses,
> who divided the waters before them
> to make Himself a name for all time,
> <sup>13</sup>     who led them through the deeps
> so that they did not stumble-as a horse in the desert,
> <sup>14</sup> like a beast descending to the plain?"
> 'Twas the Spirit of the LORD <sup>e-</sup>gave them rest;<sup>-e</sup>
> thus did You shepherd Your people
> to win for Yourself a glorious name (Isaiah 63 NJPS)
> <sub>c-c *Hebrew* moshe 'ammo, *a play on the name Moshe (Moses)*
>
> d. *So many mss. and ancient versions; other texts "shepherds."*
>
> e-e *Emendation yields "guided them.*"</sub>

The "test" of miracles done with the presence of the Holy Spirit limits the comparison to one: parting and crossing the Red Sea.

In the *Jewish Study Bible*, Benjamin D. Sommer explains how this passage may be understood in different ways:

> **11:** *They* (Hebrew "he") *remembered*: The subject of this verb is not clear: "He" may refer to God or to the nation as a collective. It is also possible to translate, "He who pulled his people out [of the water] remembered the ancient days," but even then it is not clear whether "He who pulled..." refers to God or Moses. *Where is He who brought...* The identity of the speaker here through 14a is not clear. One possibility is that the Judeans speak, wondering where their savior is (so most rabbinic commentators). Alternatively, God may ask these questions, as if saying, "Long ago I saved Israel-whatever became of that side of Me?" In that case, vv. 11b-14 mark the beginning of God's movement from wrath to grace. *Along with*, alternatively, "Specifically." *Shepherd of His flock:* The flock is the nation Israel; the shepherd is either Moses or God. (If the translation "shepherds" found in the translator's note *d* is correct, then this word refers to Moses and Aaron and perhaps to Miriam).<sup>`1`</sup>

There are alternate ways to treat the passage but when the description in Exodus is considered, the miracle was done by God. The capitalization in the translation of the Jewish Publication Society reflects their belief the LORD, YHVH, performed the miracle.

In addition to parting the water Isaiah includes two additional terms, *shepherd* and *glorious name*. Both of these terms are used to describe God. These too describe Jesus: *shepherd* (John 10:11-16; Hebrew 13:20, 1 Peter 2:25, 5:4) and glorious name (Philippians 2:9-10; Hebrews 1:4).

**Peter's Full Speech**
There are other aspects of Peter's speech which should be taken into consideration:

- Jesus is *the Word* (10:36)
- Jesus is Lord of All (10:36)
- The miracles of Jesus were specifically on those oppressed by the devil (10:38)
- Ate and drank with Him after being raised from the dead (10:41)
- The one appointed to judge the living and the dead (10:42)
- His name brings forgiveness of sins (10:43)

How would a non-Jew understand these attributes Peter uses to describe Jesus? A Roman Centurion understands the title *Lord* as one of divinity. It is how they are to call Caesar, the God-man ruling the Empire. Forgiving sins and judging both the living and the dead are things only God can do.

Finally, no where does Peter make reference to the Father. He only speaks of Jesus, the Holy Spirit, and God. In fact, the verse in question implies the Holy Spirit is God:

> how God anointed Jesus of Nazareth with the Holy Spirit and with power. He went about doing good and healing all who were oppressed by the devil, for God [**the Holy Spirit**] was with him.

**Summary**
Isaiah 63 strongly suggests the deity of one who works miracles with the Holy Spirit. In his letter, Peter reinforces the connection to Isaiah:

> For you were straying like sheep, but have now returned to the Shepherd and Overseer of your souls. (1 Peter 2:25)
> And when the chief Shepherd appears, you will receive the unfading crown of glory.
> (1 Peter 5:4)

In addition, a Roman Centurion would likely understand the other things Peter says about Jesus as indicating His position as God. Finally, as the Holy Spirit was given while Peter was speaking, the lack of "Father" in Peter's speech can only mean God is Son, Spirit, and Father.

---

<sub>1. Benjamin D. Sommer, *The Jewish Study Bible*, Edited by Adele Berlin and Marc Zvi Brettler, Oxford University Press, 2004, p. 929</sub>